# Checking dynamically generated element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please consider the following code:

```
function autoRecursiveLoad(checkingElementId) {
    if (checkingElementId.length) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        var targetId = $("#targetContent");
        var requestUrl = $('#ajaxUrl').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            complete: function(){
                autoRecursiveLoad(checkingElementId);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                targetId.append(data);
            }, 
            error: function(e) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

in the code: `checkingElementId` is the id of the dynamically generated element. I used `checkingElementId.length` to see if it already exists yet, if not, send ajax request to load the content, create div with the id of `checkingElementId` and then appends to `targetId`, then perform recursive call.

The problem is the div with id of `checkingElementId` is generated successfully but the code to check if it exists (`checkingElementId.length`) never worked. Hence, the above function will loop forever. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is checkingElementId here? Its not possible to rectify it without looking at your html code

Comment: You never change the value of `checkingElementId` so whatever it is it can never stop the loop.

Comment: using `async: false` is very poor practice as it blocks the UI

Comment: I already mentioned in the question: checkingElementId is the id of dynamically generated div appended to targetId when send ajax request with requestUrl. I dont need to update this checkingElementId because it is dynamically generated and appended to the page. Surely, most of the time ajax call is in async mode, but in some cases ajax must be in sync (async:false) to meet the specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is the best solution or not, but this works for me, I trigger the DOMNodeInserted event on the fly, so the function is updated as follows:

```
function autoRecursiveLoad(checkingElementId) {
    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', checkingElementId, function () {
        // do something when the new dynamically generated item (checkingElementId) added to the page
     });
    if (checkingElementId.length) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        var targetId = $("#targetContent");
        var requestUrl = $('#ajaxUrl').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            complete: function(){
                autoRecursiveLoad(checkingElementId);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                targetId.append(data);
            }, 
            error: function(e) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```